# Symfony 4 MSSQL sqlsrv: could not find driver

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, sqlsrv, symfony4

I want to upgrade my project to symfony 4, but the doctrine doesn't seem to find the mssql driver needed to find my database.

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=dev

 In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 125:

 An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
```

What stands out is the fact that the error occurs in MySQLDriver.php, while I explicitely tell symfony that I want to use a sqlsrv driver.

These are my doctrine.yaml settings:

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): 'sqlsrv://my_user:my_password@my_host/my_dbname'

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'sqlsrv'
        host: 'my_host'
        user: 'my_user'
        password: 'my_password'
        dbname: 'my_dbname'
        port: 'null'

        #server_version: '5.7'
        #charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

phpinfo shows that the driver can be found

[image]

[Update]

The webapp shows a much clearer error. For some reason it's loading some kind of default settings.

[image]

Comment: You told that you want to upgrade to Symfony4, so in Symfony3 the sqlsrv driver was working?

Comment: does your php info also include "sqlsrv" not just "pdo_sqlsrv" as specified in this guide? - https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/blob/PHP-7.0-Linux/LinuxTutorial.md

Comment: Have you checked your error.log? Is there any error? Have you also upgraded php to 7.1? Maybe you're loading the wrong php.ini in console?

Comment: @JackSkeletron I'm loading the correct php.ini. I'll check the error.log.  I upgraded from 7.1 to to 7.2,

Comment: @GiantJelly Yes

Comment: @JackSkeletron Which error.log?

Comment: @rmsluimers sorry i ment have you edited the php.ini of your cli (in addition to the  apache php.ini). Apache error.log.

Comment: I don't run Apache. This is MSSQL, not MySQL.

Comment: Apache is a web server, not an rdbms, there you can find the error logged in when executing your command. I don't know which web server you are using, maybe IIS or Nginx, just check the error log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171253/discussion-between-rmsluimers-and-jack-skeletron).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171259/discussion-between-jack-skeletron-and-rmsluimers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put this configuration for doctrine, check [the doctrine config referenc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html)e

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                driver: sqlsrv
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

I've added **sqlsrv** (you said that you've installed it) and not **pdo_sqlsrv** as [it causes problems](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/a7eb74ea296c85a06c324088b2d6e10f6b448fae/docs/en/reference/configuration.rst).

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, but the issue is actually caused by a bug that somehow overrides the url setting. Not setting the url solves the issue, which luckily is possible. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration